# Limit minor version decimal point

Tags: 2013, versioning

I'm using Sharepoint 2013.

I would like to know if it's possible to limit the decimal point of the minor version.

For example, currently the minor version goes from 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, 1,12..... Can we set in such a way that after 1.9, the version will be 2.0, 2.1, 2.2.... 2.9, 3.0, 3.1...?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no ootb approach on limiting the number of minor versions to allow, you'll need to write an event receiver to do minor version checking and publishing of a major version.

Answer (score 1):

Library Settings and select Versioning Settings

Under Document Version History section, check the option for "Keep drafts for the following number of major versions". Enter the number of versions you want to keep.

Hope this helps

Reference:
Click [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/87260d60-f79c-4c8e-ac0c-9909eca36b07/minor-version-limit-exceeded)!

Comment: That has nothing to do with what he wants to accomplish